# Simple Sprite Kit Scene setup going wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios7, sprite-kit

I'm trying to set up a simple Sprite Kit setup.
All I'm doing is re-creating the default xCode template 'Sprite Kit Game' from an 'Empty Application'.

It keeps crashing on the *skView.showsFPS = YES;* line. Which I can't explain. Can you? Thanks!

Some code:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  MenuController *menuController = [[MenuController alloc] init];
  self.window.rootViewController = menuController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

**MenuController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;
  skView.showsFPS = YES;
  skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

  MultiplayerView *gameView = [MultiplayerView sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
  gameView.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

  [skView presentScene:gameView];
}
```

When I launch this, the following error occurs:

```
2013-11-10 13:08:01.605 ByS[9419:70b] -[UIView setShowsFPS:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10c00bc60
2013-11-10 13:08:01.608 ByS[9419:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setShowsFPS:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10c00bc60'
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the interface builder, change the class of the window's view to `SKView`. Type-casting a `UIView` into `SKView` won't do anything unless the `UIView` was previously obtained by casting a `SKView`.

Comment: A good hint that this is the case is in the error: The class it lists is `UIView`, not `SKView`. In addition, the error is about the selector `setShowFPS:` not being recognized (which is implemented by SKView, but not its parent class UIView).

Comment: Thanks, but not using any storyboards here. So no interface builder. Anyway to do this in code? Thought it was the   _SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;_   line..

Comment: Re-created 'MenuController' with xib and changed the view to SKView. Perfectly working, thanks! Would be nice to avoid the xib though..

Comment: If you are doing it by code, try creating an `SKView` and assigning it to the view controller's `view` property in the `init` method of the view controller.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue when starting from a single-view or empty application, vs the usual SpriteKit template. Mine worked when I added some code I found to overwrite the loadView method. Try putting it just above your viewDidLoad in your View Controller.

```
- (void)loadView {
    CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    SKView *skView = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:applicationFrame];
    self.view = skView;
}
```

The .h file is the usual UIViewController. And remember to #import  after you have linked the framework!:

```
@interface CharacterViewController : UIViewController
```

So the full .m code would be something like:

```
@implementation CharacterViewController

- (void)loadView {
    CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    SKView *skView = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:applicationFrame];
    self.view = skView;
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"CharacterViewController viewDidLoad");
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;


    // Create and configure the scene.
    CharacterScene *character = [[CharacterScene alloc]initWithSize:CGSizeMake(skView.bounds.size.width, skView.bounds.size.height)];

    character.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    [skView presentScene:character];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can fix it fast and dirty in `prepareForSegue:` or before any other presentation

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
     UIViewController *destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController;
     SKView * skView = (SKView *)destinationVC.view;

    if (![skView isKindOfClass:[SKView class]]) {
        skView = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame: skView.frame]; // self.view.bounds
        destinationVC.view = skView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In MenuController.m replace your initialisation

`SKView *skView = (SKView *) self.view;`

with

```
SKView *skView = [[SKView alloc initWithFrame : self.view.frame];
```

- You just need to initialize object of SKView by giving frame of self.view not by assigning a reference object of self.view.