# Crash calling a ViewController implementing a SpriteKit scene

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, viewcontroller, skscene, skview

I am trying to call a viewcontrollerB from a viewcontrollerA with the following code:

```
ViewControllerB *vc = [[ViewControllerB alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Within the viewcontrollerB I have the following code:

```
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;

skView.showsFPS = NO;
skView.showsNodeCount = NO;

// Create and configure the scene.
SKScene * scene = [MainScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
//scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;

// Present the scene.
[skView presentScene:scene];
```

I receive the error:

[UIView setShowsFPS:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

So I have read and implemented the solution wrote in the following link:

[Simple Sprite Kit Scene setup going wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889543/simple-sprite-kit-scene-setup-going-wrong)

But I have the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved with the following code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
ViewControllerB *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerB"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do this...

```
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;

skView.showsFPS = NO;
```

...you're telling the compiler that your view is a `SKView` but apparently it's not.  The error message says that it's a plain `UIView`. You need to look at how a `MSPageViewControllerB` is defined and what type of object its `view` property is defined as being.